# How to use txt content to onclick="doAjaxCall(' ')?

Tags: php, onclick

I use voice xml to select logo or movie. Put `logo.svg` or `movie.php` in the `txt` file. Then I use php to load the `logo.svg` or `movie.php` to the `$theData`.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);

// define your file name as a variable
$myFile = "voice.txt";

// get a FILE HANDLE to the file: 'r' means set permission to read
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

//read the entire file and store the contents in the variable $theData
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));

// close the file so it will be OK to use later
fclose($fh);

//echo  whatever is in the file back to the browser
echo $theData;



// PART 2
// get a FILE HANDLE to the file: 'a' means set permission to read
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Error trying to open with a");

$noData = "no msgs";

//read the entire file and store the contents in the variable $theData
$theData = fwrite($fh, $noData);

// close the file so it will be OK to use later
fclose($fh)

?>
```

Now I want to show either of them on the webs.
I use:

```
<input class="logo" type="button" value="Call (832) 271-6319 " onclick="doAjaxCall('  ');"/>
```

How can I do it? Should I use javascript?

Comment: I use this in html   <input class="logo" type="button" value="Call (832) 271-6319 " onclick="doAjaxCall('movie.php');"/>

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. The onclick allows you to add a javascript function. You can make an ajax call from this function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. 
The onclick allows you to add a javascript function like

```
<input onclick="myFunction()" />
```

You can make an ajax call from this function. 
Or you can use jquery and attach a function to the input click event.

```
$(".logo").click(function(){
.....
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I call and say logo,and the webpage will show the logo.svg.How can I do with it.